# Is there any advantage to importing a module by relative path vs actual package name?

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I have a folder structure as below.

```
project/
-> app/
--> __init__.py (has db = SQLAlchemy(app))
--> model.py
```

I need to import db in model.py. I can either import it using

```
from app import db
```

or

```
from . import db
```

Is there a difference between the two? Does one method have any advantages over the other method?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute imports are preferred because they are quite clear and straightforward. It is easy to tell exactly where the imported resource is, just by looking at the statement. In fact, [pep8](https://pep8.org/#imports) explicitly recommends absolute imports.

Sometimes, however, absolute imports can get quite verbose, depending on the complexity of the directory structure. Imagine having a statement like this:

```
from package1.subpackage2.subpackage3.subpackage4.module5 import function6
```

This looks ridiculous! Right?

So, Relative imports comes into picture. A relative import specifies the resource to be imported relative to the current location—that is, the location where the import statement is.

Above complex import statement becomes:

```
from ..subpackage4.module5 import function6
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So unless I have a long tree of subpackages, it's always recommended to use absolute imports over relative imports?

Comment: Yes, always try to use absolute one! this is one use case of relative imports in case of complex/long tree. It's completely depend on your project structure.Unfortunately, relative imports can be messy, particularly for shared projects where directory structure is likely to change.

Comment: Please upvote it, if it helps in your case so that others would get the benefit.